# Como hacer push a github con contenido

Tags: git, git-push

Buenas ya había hecho push anteriormente pero, esta vez le agregue al repositorio una licencia(no se si sea este el fallo) y cuando hago pull y luego push la consola me dice que todo esta a actualizado sin embargo, en mi github no me reflejan los cambio. Les adjunto la foto para que puedan verificar mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y ya hiciste git add y commit de los cambios que quieres subir?

Comment: ahhh no men, ahora si me pasexd, tenia tiempo que no usaba git que olvide los mas básico